# Number of zeros of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, entire-functions

I want to find the zeros of the function
\begin{equation}
e^{\gamma z}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)e^{-\frac{z}{n}}-1
\end{equation}
for some constant $\gamma$. The function is clearly equal to zero at $z=0$. But I am unable to decide whether it has zero at other points in the complex plane as well. I can not use the Casorati Weierstrass theorem since the function does not have any essential singularity in the finite plane. It is actually an entire function having oder $1$. Any entire function having infinite number of zeros have its convergence exponent $>1$. Can we use it in some way to find the zeros of the given function in any way? Please help.

Comment: *Hint*: You have an essential singularity at $\infty$, use it.

Comment: @user10354138 Please explain.

Comment: I would look at $1$ and a bunch of negative numbers